# Store number as concatenation between column name from dataframe and another string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to save the averages of different variables from a dataframe with the name of that variable plus the string '_mean'. I tried this but I'm getting this error:

```
cols = ['col1','col2', 'col3']

for x in cols:
    df[x].name + '_mean'= df[x].mean()

   File "<ipython-input-212-19ab5c9bf93b>", line 2
    data_adults[x].name + '_mean'= data_adults[x].mean()
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

What's wrong? Thnaks!

Comment: what's wrong with `df[cols].mean()` if you just want them in a different object? You typically want to avoid creating an arbitrary number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just index the new col with `x`, like this:

```py
cols = ['col1','col2', 'col3']

for x in cols:
    locals().update({x + '_mean': df[x].mean()})
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I'm not trying to add new columns, I just want to store the averages in separate objects

Comment: @Charles if I understand you correctly, you want new variables named `col1_mean,` etc... edited my answer